# How create a index for array string in mongodatabase

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, indexing

i have a collection that i have a array string,my question is how i can create a index for that field array in my collections.
** selectionRaw:[]**, is posible create a index to search a word inside of that array of string, how i can do that in monogo.
I try this but don't work because text don't work with array
`MIPsSchema.index({ title: "text", mipName: "text" , sectionsRaw: "text" });`

Answer (score 0):

If your documents have essentially this shape:

```js
{ title: "A", mipName: "X", sectionsRaw: [ "X","Y","Z" ] }
{ title: "B", mipName: "X", sectionsRaw: [ "Q","R" ] }
```

then you can create a regular index on `sectionsRaw`:

```js
db.yourCollection.createIndex({'sectionsRaw':1});
```

Queries involving `sectionsRaw` e.g. `find({'sectionsRaw':'R'})` will now be index-optimized.